# Why do I get Type Error on one line, but not the others

Tags: python, typeerror

So, I have this piece of code which is used to add/subtract from the x and y value in a list with dictionaries. The thing is, the code must account for the fact that the dictionary can be given like a string with quotes around it. So, for that reason I use `ast.literal_eval(point)` to turn the string into a dictionary. However, for some reason with this line that has been changed following commands don't work like they do with the others.

Commands in question: `point['x'] += offset['x']` and  `point['y'] += offset['y']`

I am very confused, both with the issue in question and the code in general as it was translated from js.

```
import ast


def parse(point):
    if type(point) == dict:
        return point
    else:
        return ast.literal_eval(point)


def shift(offset, points):
    modified_points = points.copy()
    for point in modified_points:
        arg_type = type(point)
        parse(point)
        point['x'] += offset['x']
        point['y'] += offset['y']
        print(point)
    return modified_points


polyline = [
    {'x': 0,'y': 0},
    {'x': 10, 'y': 10},
    '{"x": 20, "y": 20}',
    {'x': 30, 'y': 30}
]

results = shift({'x': 10, 'y': -5}, polyline)
print(results)
```

The error goes as following:

```
  File "/home/selby/PycharmProjects/10thPractical/3rd.py", line 37, in <module>
    results = shift({'x': 10, 'y': -5}, polyline)
  File "/home/selby/PycharmProjects/10thPractical/3rd.py", line 19, in shift
    point['x'] += offset['x']
TypeError: string indices must be integers

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: `point` is a copy of `polyline` which is a list of dictionaries. Lists are indexed with numbers not strings

Comment: You do not store the return value when you call `parse(point)`.

Answer (score 0):

You do not store the return value when you call `parse(point)`, i.e. `point` is still a string when you try to use it in `point['x'] += offset['x']` (as the error indicates).

Replace the line with `point = parse(point)`, and the error will disappear.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense, do you have any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: Omg, thank you so much, that fixed it. I guess a similar issue is with the modified_points return, now I just have to figure out how to fix it?

Comment: Rather than making a copy and looping over the copy, I would suggest to create an empty `modified_points` and `append` the parsed points when looping over the original `points`.

Comment: Oh, I will try that, thank you!